# Is there any way to hide agenda date header?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

If i set `(org-agenda-format-date "")` it still shows empty line. 
If i set `(org-agenda-overriding-header "")` i get `org-agenda-list: Args out of range: 0, 1` error.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with `(let ((org-agenda-overriding-header "")) (org-agenda-list))`: that should be the way to do what you want but there seems to be bug here. You should report that on the org-mode mailing list. I don't think that `org-agenda-format-date` is useful for what you want to do.

Comment: I submitted a [bug report on this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2019-07/msg00003.html)  and it is [reportedly fixed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2019-07/msg00018.html). You might want to try again after updating. Thank you for finding the bug!